# EditRecord failed because of the default alias Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a simple form in access which contains a macro that saves the edit time and a flag after the current record is updated.

However when the macro attempts to execute I get an error that says:

> EditRecord failed because the default alias represent a record which is read only

I have been searching over the internet for an answer but I haven't been able to find anything yet that helps.

This form only has one user on it at a time and none of the other forms using the same table are open while it's being used.

I have **pk** and it's an `Auto Increment` without duplicate values. Beside this I have changed the locking status to **No Lock**

I also get an error when I use `DoCmd` in my macro instead of `openQuery`.

The data mode in `openQuery` is "Edit" so it doesn't create any errors.

I'm using the Macro Tools in Access 2016. I'm not sure about the differences between an Access Macro and Access VBA but this is an Access Macro.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
SetWarning Off
Repeat Count:1

Open Query:
UPDATE table
SET editDate = now, reviewDate = now, flag = 0
WHERE ID=[Forms]![FormName].[ID];

view: Datasheet
Data Mode: Edit

GoToRecord: Next
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the code in your macro? Although I think your problem might be with the form not allowing edits.

Comment: Additionally to showing your macro code, please also clarify if you actually mean an Access Macro or Access VBA.

Comment: If you converted this macro to VBA it might give you a more meaningful error code. However I suspect the issue is that the current record is in an unsaved state when you are then trying to update via another method. I suspect this is what the macro refers to as an aliased record ? So try saving the current record before the update query runs.

Comment: You should probably use 3 SetValue macro actions during the BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: Dear Minty thanks for your help , I have checked my macro and the option of convert to vba is disable and type of macro in my event is Embeded macro, and about unsaved state that you mentioned -even for the first record i have to save it before perform update ?

Comment: To be fair this would be easy to achieve in 2 or 3 lines of VBA in the after_update property of a suitable field(s). I don't use Embedded or Normal macros so can't really assist. What event is this macro being triggered by ?